# Refreshable pivot table connected to an external source

Tags: excel, vba, mariadb, pivot-table, powerpivot

I am planning to deploy an Excel file where the users would only need to refresh to see the updated data. I can currently do this by sending out a new Excel file every time.

What I have:

- Office 365
- MariaDB on Digital Ocean

What I want:

Create a pivot table/data model connected to the database and have the data updated real time upon refresh.

I can do this on my own via ODBC but when sharing the file, it asks for the credentials which is saved on my ODBC file. Ideally, I don't want to share the credentials even though it's read-only.

Is there an alternative to ODBC so I can easily share the refreshable pivot table?

Comment: Do they need the Excel file?  Or is simply what they are used to.  I ask because it may be simpler in the long run to remove Excel from the dataflow, and simply build web page(s) that present the data.

Comment: The Excel file is needed. For now, what I did is to install the ODBC on each workmachine.